# ng-attr-data-toggle shorthand: display nothing for false

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, attributes

How to modify this line

```
<span ng-attr-data-toggle="{{ isValueTrue ? 'toggle' : 'notToggle' }}"></span>
```

so that it displays

```
<span data-toggle="toggle"></span>
```

for true and

```
<span></span>
```

for false.

Comment: Maybe `ng-if` will do the trick for you? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: @Fidel90 ng-if for attribute?

Comment: No, I thought of sth. like: `<span data-toggle="toggle" ng-if="isValueTrue"></span><span ng-if="!isValueTrue"></span>`. Not a very clean solution, indeed. If you need this in several places in your app maybe a directive would be a better bet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you'll want to set an ng-if as mentioned in the comments like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/841Lfjfe/

Angular:

```
function Controller() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.toggle = false;
  vm.doToggle = doToggle;

  function doToggle() {
     vm.toggle = (!vm.toggle) ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.doToggle()">
    Toggle
</button>
<hr>
<span ng-if="ctrl.toggle">Toggled</span>
```